# Adding toolbar via PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, toolbar

Through tutorials I learned how to add a toolbutton to the plugins-toolbar via python. Now I wonder how to add a complete toolbar with toolbarbuttons via python.

Can anybody give some example-code?

Answer (score 20):

You can use [the addToolBar() API call via QgisInterface](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a882199db87f1b58bd5fc9b3d5db00d28) (i.e. iface) to create a custom toolbar:

```
class MyPlugin:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        # Add toolbar 
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar("My_ToolBar")

        # Create actions 
        self.someact = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/MyPlugin/icons/someactionicon.png"),
                               QCoreApplication.translate("MyPlugin", "My Action"),
                               self.iface.mainWindow())

        # Connect action signals to slots
        self.someact.triggered.connect(self.doSomething)

        # Add actions to the toolbar
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.someact)

    def unload(self):
        # remove toolbar on plugin unload
        del self.toolbar

    def doSomething(self):
        # slot for action
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I have posted an answer to a post of mine here:

[How can I add a second Toolbar Button and Dialog to a QGIS plugin built with Plugin Builder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194787/how-can-i-add-a-second-toolbar-button-and-dialog-to-a-qgis-plugin-built-with-plu)

that may also answer your question