# ToolBar icon images missing

Tags: qgis, python, hydrology, toolbar, icon

[very early build ~ zip file](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FKD/OMZH/HVF6ZFCY/FKDOMZHHVF6ZFCY.zip)

I am getting blank outputs for button images in a custom toolbar. Although the button information populates the dockable toolbar, they lack respective icons [see Fig.1]

Much of the following code was referenced from [Add toolbar via Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/how-to-add-a-toolbar-via-python)

```
def initGui(self):
    # Add toolbar

    self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar("Graphic Groundwater")
    self.toolbar.setObjectName("Graphic Groundwater")

    # Create actions
    self.getDEM = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/getDEM.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Get DEM Map"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.getTopo = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/getTopo.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Get Topo Map"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.addBase = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/addBase.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Add Base Area"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.addNewBase = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/addNewBase.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Add New Base Area"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.addRiver = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/addRiver.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Add River"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.addStress = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/addStress.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Add Stress"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.addGrid = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/addGrid.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Add Grid"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.refreshGrid = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/refreshGrid.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Refresh Attributes"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.runModel = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/runModel.png"),
                           QCoreApplication.translate("Groundwater Modeling", "Run Model"),
                           self.iface.mainWindow())

    # Connect action signals to slots
    self.getDEM.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.getTopo.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.addBase.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.addNewBase.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.addRiver.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.addStress.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.addGrid.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.refreshGrid.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.runModel.triggered.connect(self.run)

    # Add actions to the toolbar
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.getDEM)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.getTopo)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.addBase)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.addNewBase)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.addRiver)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.addStress)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.addGrid)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.refreshGrid)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.runModel)

def unload(self):
    # remove toolbar on plugin unload
    del self.toolbar
```

[Fig.1]
[image: blank toolbar]

The associated resource_rc file might also be of some diagnosis assistance...

```
<qresource prefix=":/plugins/graphicgroundwater/" >
    <file>GraphicGroundwater.png</file>
    <file>getDEM.png</file>
    <file>getTopo.png</file>
    <file>addBase.png</file>
    <file>addNewBase.png</file>
    <file>addRiver.png</file>
    <file>addStress.png</file>
    <file>addGrid.png</file>
    <file>refreshGrid.png</file>
    <file>runModel.png</file>
</qresource>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the basic directory structure of the *uninstalled* plugin is:

```
GraphicGroundwater
  icon.png
  icons
    addBase.png
    ...
  resources.qrc
  ...
```

You will want something like this in `resources.qrc` (see [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html)):

```xml
<qresource prefix="/plugins/GraphicGroundwater" >
    <file>icon.png</file>
    <file>icons/getDEM.png</file>
    <file>icons/getTopo.png</file>
    <file>icons/addBase.png</file>
    <file>icons/addNewBase.png</file>
    <file>icons/addRiver.png</file>
    <file>icons/addStress.png</file>
    <file>icons/addGrid.png</file>
    <file>icons/refreshGrid.png</file>
    <file>icons/runModel.png</file>
 </qresource>
```

Where `icon.png = GraphicGroundwater.png` and is your plugin's representative icon.

**Notes:**

- The paths inside the `<file>` tags are relative to the .qrc file's directory. The prefix string just helps define a unique identifier to be used in the generated `resources_rc.py` file, where the icons themselves are embedded. Alternatively, you can skip a resource file and just define a system path to icons, but the use of a resources file is good form.
- The colon is not needed in the `resource.qrc` file's prefix, nor the trailing slash. Use the colon when referencing the resource in your code, as you have correctly done in your `QAction` icon paths:

  ```
  QIcon(":<prefix>/<file>")
  # e.g. 
  QIcon(":/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/icons/addBase.png")
  ```
- You will want to avoid using spaces in object names, e.g.:

  ```
  self.toolbar.setObjectName("graphic_groundwater")  # or graphicgroundwater
  ```
- When [setting a translation string](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#translate), generally the first parameter is the parent class's name of the `initGui` function, e.g. GraphicGroundwater, if that is what it is:

  ```
  QCoreApplication.translate("GraphicGroundwater", "Get DEM Map")
  ```

There are a couple of other assumptions you may want to check, if above solution doesn't seem to work:

- Verify your are generating the correct `resources_rc.py` module from your .qrc, using `pyrcc4`.
- Verify you are importing the resultant module, e.g. `import resources_rc`.

Comment: Took your advice on all accounts for sake of streamlining things.  Unfortunately, something in the build still seems to be preventing the images being referenced.

Comment: Would there be a conflict between the central file this code is excerpted from (graphicgroundwater.py), and the as of yet unedited (ui_graphicgroundwater.py)?  When the blank toolbar buttons are selected, the ui properly opens, although it to is currently blank (yet to write).  A novice idea on the cause of this error; is it possible the icon image resolutions would cause a 'no-show'?  All the documentation I have looked through states the QGIS toolbars are happy with 24x24, which is what the resoucres in question are...

Comment: You will need to give more info on your project, or find a means of posting the project files. Are you indeed using a Makefile or other method of *deploying* the plugin to ~/.qgis/python/plugins/graphicgroundwater/? And in that file, are you using `pyrcc4` to generate (then install) the resultant `resources_rc.py`?

Comment: The icon size of 24x24 if fine, though realize the QGIS icon interface spec goes up to 32x32. Your best bet is to create the icons as SVG 1.0 (e.g. in Inkscape) so that they are resolution-independent.

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom dakcarto.  I will look into the SVG 1.0 soon, but priority will be to actually get the file structure stable and working!  Compressed directory added for diagnosis at crown of posting.  There is deffinatly a major amount of ongoing work on this...

Comment: Tested your plugin and it only needs one change: the resource path's prefix needs to match exactly (evidently it's case-sensitive), i.e. needs to be `:/plugins/graphicgroundwater/...` instead of `:/plugins/GraphicGroundwater/...`. Also, you will generally want Python modules imported first, e.g. move `import os.path` to before PyQt4 imports. Lastly, check out the [Plugin Reloader](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugin_reloader/) plugin, which can reload your plugin inside of QGIS. Helpful when your are doing plugin dev.

Comment: These small syntax errors are the problems I often unintentionally create for myself, being so new to writing.  I truly appreciate your taking the time to help resolve this issue.  The plugin reloader looks interesting.  It would probably provide to be much quicker than my current workflow of constantly resaving in PyScripter, recompiling (if needed) then duplicating the testing folder to the QGIS directory.  Once again, Kudos to you and this forum for the wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a solution, pretty straight forward:

I am using QGIS 2.6, and the plugin builder 2.0.3 -- both downloaded within the last couple of weeks.

The plugin builder creates a "resources.qrc" file, while creating a main script with this reference:

`import resources_rc` at line 27

Until I removed the trailing "_rc" in the main script, I also did not have an icon in the bar, but did have a blank spot [icon-less] which would run my test plugin.   On correcting the main script import reference, the icon appeared.   This fix also eliminated a QGIS startup error that appeared if the plugin had been successfully installed in an earlier run/instance of QGIS [an error that did not appear otherwise, later while running QGIS or the plugin]: more/less: failing to see a resources_rc.

May I suggest (to whomever) that either the file name or the import reference in the plugin builder be corrected, to match?