# How can I add a second Toolbar Button and Dialog to a QGIS plugin built with Plugin Builder?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I want to create a toolbar with 2 buttons, each button opening a different form.

The steps I followed are:

- Created a plugin using Plugin builder
- Created a toolbar with 2 buttons by doing the necessary modifications in the implementation file.

Until here, everything works fine, so when first button is clicked, the corresponding form opens correctly. This form is the one created by the Plugin builder.

Then I want to have a second form which will open when the second button is clicked.
So:

- Created a new form in Qt designer (form2.ui),
- Translated the ui file to py file (make) and imported the class from the translated py file into the implementation file, got an instance of the class (self.dlg2 = Ui_form2())

and in the run() method of the implementation file I wrote:

```
def run2(self):
    self.dlg2.show()
    result = self.dlg2.exec_()
```

But then I get an error message that this new form has no .show() method. Should it inherit something in order to implement the .show() method?
But how can I modify the code of the second form in order to inherit something since all changes in the translated py file from the ui file cannot be saved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I did to implement a second Toolbar button and its corresponding dialog:

1. Edit the `plugin.py` file to add a `run2()` method, a `self.dlg2` variable, a new action in `initGui()`, and this import:

   ```
   from plugin_dialog2 import pluginDialog2
   ```
2. Copy and paste the UI file and rename it as `form2.ui` (optionally, open it in Qt-Designer and change the `windowTitle` property to distinguish both dialogs visually).
3. Copy and paste the `plugin_dialog.py` file and rename it as `plugin_dialog2.py`
4. Edit the `plugin_dialog2.py` file adjusting the class name to `pluginDialog2`, the first parameter of super to `abcDialog2`, and the name of the UI file:

   ```
   import os
   from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

   FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
       os.path.dirname(__file__), 'form2.ui'))

   class abcDialog2(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           """Constructor."""
           super(abcDialog2, self).__init__(parent)
           self.setupUi(self)
   ```

You can download a demo plugin with two dialogs from [here](http://downloads.tuxfamily.org/tuxgis/tmp/abc.zip).

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is working fine and at the same time it gave a better understanding of the plugin building.. So, I would assume that the above procedure can be applied more times, if for example I want to have 3 or 4 buttons, each one opening a different form. But my 3rd button doesn' t appear on the toolbar. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Right, it should work as many times as you need, as long as you keep an order naming variables, classes, and the like. For instance, to add your 3rd button you would need to add a new action in `initGui()`, this way:         `self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'plugin3'),
            callback=self.run3,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())`

Comment: Well, it works ok in the end after I restarted my computer...

Answer (score 17):

**1**. Use **Plugin builder** to create a new plugin

The files created are shown in the following picture

[image]

**2**. Convert the resources file (**resources.qrc**) to Python file (**resources.py**) using the **OSGeo4W Shell**

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

After that, if you **look inside the plugin folder**, you will notice a new *.py file*, the **resources.py** file that was just created.
The plugin can now be installed and opened through the main QGIS menu>Manage and install Plugins.

**3**.**HOW TO CREATE THE TOOLBAR AND THE TOOLS (buttons) AND ADD THE TOOLS ON THE TOOLBAR**

Open with an editor the **my_toolbar.py** file and in the section of the **initGui(self)** write:

```
def initGui(self):

    self.toolBar = self.iface.addToolBar("MY TOOLBAR tools")
    self.toolBar.setObjectName("MY TOOLBAR tools")

    self.act1 = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/Myplugintoolbar/icon.png"), QCoreApplication.translate("IMPRESStoolbar", "Tool1"), self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.act2 = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/Myplugintoolbar/icon.png"), QCoreApplication.translate("IMPRESStoolbar", "Tool2"), self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.act3 = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/Myplugintoolbar/icon.png"), QCoreApplication.translate("IMPRESStoolbar", "Tool3"), self.iface.mainWindow())
```

This way three buttons/tools have been created.

In order for the buttons to appear on the toolbar, continue writing the following:

```
    self.toolBar.addAction(self.act1)
    self.toolBar.addAction(self.act2)
    self.toolBar.addAction(self.act3)
```

In order for the buttons when clicked to open a gui continue writing the following:

```
    QObject.connect(self.act1, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.runtool1)
    QObject.connect(self.act2, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.runtool2)
    QObject.connect(self.act3, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.runtool3)
```

**runtool1**, **runtool2** and **runtool3** methods are defined later as following in order to open a different gui for each button

```
def runtool1(self):
     self.dlgtool1.show()

def runtool2(self):
     self.dlgtool2.show()

def runtool3(self):
     self.dlgtool3.show()
```

That way when **tool1 button** is clicked the gui **dlgtool1** will open, when **tool2 button** is clicked the **dlgtool2** will open and when **tool3 button** is clicked the **dlgtool3** gui will open.

**dlgtool1**, **dlgtool2** and **dlgtool3** should be **variables** pointing at the **ui files** **representing the dialogs**.

So the **dialogs** have to be:

- **created**,
- **imported into the main py file** (**my_toolbar.py**) and
- **assigned to variables** (**dlgtool1**, **dlgtool2** and **dlgtool3** ) in order to **get an instance** of them.

**In order to create the dialogs**:

- Copy the files **my_toolbar_dialog.py** and **my_toolbar_dialog_base.ui**
  and paste them inside another folder so you can rename them.
  Do this as many times as needed, for this example three times.
  **Then copy these new files and paste them back to the Myplugintoolbar folder**
  [image]

Open **Form_dlgtool1_dialog.py** with an editor in order to apply the following modifications:

**From**:

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'my_toolbar_dialog_base.ui'))

class MyplugintoolbarDialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyplugintoolbarDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

**Change to**:

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Form_dlgtool1.ui'))

class Formdlgtool1Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Formdlgtool1Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Follow the same procedure for the other two files (**Form_dlgtool2_dialog.py** and **Form_dlgtool3_dialog.py**)

Then, **in order to import the dialogs into the main file** open **my_toolbar.py file** with the editor and **import** the following

```
from Form_dlgtool1_dialog import Formdlgtool1Dialog

from Form_dlgtool2_dialog import Formdlgtool2Dialog

from Form_dlgtool3_dialog import Formdlgtool3Dialog
```

Finally, **in order to get an instance of them**, write the following inside the **def __init__(self, iface)** section:

```
self.dlgtool1 = Formdlgtool1Dialog()
self.dlgtool2 = Formdlgtool2Dialog()
self.dlgtool3 = Formdlgtool3Dialog()
```

Now, you can open the ui files in the QtDesigner and customize them. Then reload the plugin toolbar inside QGIS to get hte following result

[image]