# NameError: global name 'QObject' is not defined - When I add a second Toolbar Button and Dialog to a QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I have a problem  when I add a second Toolbar Button and Dialog to a QGIS plugin, I load my plugin in "Manage an installing plugins..." but this error appears

[image]

This is a part of my .py

[image]

What is the problem?

I use this link: [How can I add a second Toolbar Button and Dialog to a QGIS plugin built with Plugin Builder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194787/how-can-i-add-a-second-toolbar-button-and-dialog-to-a-qgis-plugin-built-with-plu)

Comment: Please add error messages and your code as text to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject` to import section of your `.py` file.

`NameError: global name '***' is not defined` means roughly that you use an object you have not defined yet. So you have to define an object (like `a = 1`. `a` is an `int` object here) or you have to import that object which exists somewhere.

Comment: You should also add ... from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL